# How to use activerecord.aj file's method in spring roo

Tags: sql, spring, activerecord, aspectj, spring-roo

I am trying to get value of total number of raw in my table in spring roo project. This can be done by built-in method of Spring roo's aspectJ file.

The method defined as the below in `UserAccount_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj` file:

```
  public static long UserAccount.countUserAccounts() {
         return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) FROM UserAccount o", Long.class).getSingleResult();
  }
```

I want to print this long value to my jspx page. How to call this method and from where?
Need help. Thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the Controller method that handles the related request:

1: Push-in the controller method you,e.g. `show` method

2: Modify that method run the query and place the result available for view layer:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
    ...
    Long count = UserAccount.countUserAccounts();
    uiModel.addAttribute("countUserAccounts", count);
    ...
}
```

3: Modify the jspx as needed.

Comment: Thanx sir. actually I did the same. :)